# Two separate text fields using a DatePicker instead of keyboard in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uitextfield

I have two separate text fields that both use a date picker to select a date, however, when I edit one, both display the same date. How do I separate the two so that each has its own date picker?

```
@IBOutlet weak var dateField1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dateField2: UITextField!
let dateFormat: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let datePicker: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
let dateFormat2: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
let datePicker2: UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dateFormat.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormat.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("updateDateField:"), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    dateField.inputView = datePicker
    dateFormat2.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    dateFormat2.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
    datePicker2.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.DateAndTime
    datePicker2.addTarget(self, action: Selector("updateDateField:"), forControlEvents:UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    delivery.inputView = datePicker2

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.toolbarHidden = false
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
}

func updateDateField(sender: UIDatePicker) {
    dateField.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    delivery.text = dateFormat2.stringFromDate(sender.date)


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check below code -

```
func updateDateField(sender: UIDatePicker) {
   if sender == datePicker
   {
    dateField.text = dateFormat.stringFromDate(sender.date)
   }
   if sender == datePicker2
   {
    delivery.text = dateFormat2.stringFromDate(sender.date)
   }


}
```

Comment: did you create 2 different datePickers?